# GSLV MK2 vs Falcon 9 - Reasons for Huge performance difference

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, isro, merlin-1d

Yesterday ISRO operated the GSLV MK2 launch vehicle, which is a medium lift launch vehicle with a capability to lift 5 tonnes to LEO.

I just compared Falcon 9 with GSLV MK2. Falcon 9 capability to lift 23 tonnes to LEO is almost 5 times as much as the GSLV. So I expect a similar difference in thrust for each rocket.

GSLV First Stage : 760 kN * 4 (L40 Straps)  + 4,700 kN (Solid core stage) = **7740kN**

Falcon 9 FT First Stage : 825 kN * 9 (Merlin 1D+) = **7425kN**

Both LVs first stages burn duration is around 160 seconds. Specific impulse also does not have much difference for both Vikas and Merlin engine. Also GSLV third stage uses a cryogenic engine with very high Specific impulse.

Still what are the main factors which allow Falcon 9 to perform **5 times better** than GSLV Mk2?

Is the second stage of GSLV the main reason?

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/why-are-rocket-mass-on-the-launch-pad-and-payload-mass-to-leo-not-strongly-corre

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biggest factor is probably the "inside-out" staging design, where the solid core burns out but is not jettisoned, while the liquid boosters continue to run.

Spaceflight101 gives the empty mass of the (steel-cased) solid stage as 28 tons (with an unremarkable 83% mass fraction); this means the otherwise decent specific impulse of the strap-on engines is horribly compromised by carrying 28 tons of dead weight for a full minute.

That unusual design is derived from the earlier PSLV launcher, which uses the same solid rocket first stage, but with smaller and shorter-burning solid strap-on boosters which drop away halfway through the first-stage burn. It was easier and cheaper  to change those out for larger liquid-fueled boosters than to design an all-new high-thrust liquid first stage for GSLV.

GSLV MkIII will be a more efficient solids-on-the-outside design, launching 10 tons to LEO from a 630 ton launch weight.

In general, you can't expect to learn much about payload by comparing launch thrust. For orbital launchers, liftoff thrust is generally correlated with liftoff weight - typically you start with a 1.15-1.5 ratio -- but liftoff weight is not closely correlated with payload, as discussed in another Q/A: [Why are rocket mass on the launch pad and payload mass to LEO not strongly correlated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/why-are-rocket-mass-on-the-launch-pad-and-payload-mass-to-leo-not-strongly-corre)

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of factors that impact the mass a Launch Vehicle can bring to orbit. In this case, what we need to look at is not only the first stage's thrust, but also its efficiency, measured in rocketry as the Specific Impulse (I<sub>sp</sub>), which indicates the energy an engine can extract from a given mass of propellants.

According to wikipedia, the GSLV MkII's first stage has a very low I<sub>sp</sub> (237s) due to its use of a solid motor, while the boosters have a slightly higher I<sub>sp</sub> (262), still fairly low for liquid engines. For comparison, the Falcon 9 Full Thrust's Merlin-1D engines rate at 282s.

Additionally, it shows on the GSLV MkII's page that the first stage burns for 100 seconds, while the strap-on boosters burn for 160 seconds. This means that for the last 60 seconds of their burn, the four liquid boosters are carrying the first stage's casing which has become pure dead weight.

Lastly, looking at the launch mass of both vehicles gives us another reason: Falcon 9 Full thrust takes off at 549 tonnes, while GSLV MkII weighs 414 tonnes. We don't know the exact propellant mass fraction for either, but most rockets are around 90% fuel by mass at takeoff — GSLV just carries much less fuel than Falcon 9 FT

Sources:

- [GSLV MkII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle)
- [Falcon 9 FT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9_Full_Thrust)

Comment: But is that enough to get 5times performance gain?

Comment: See the added paragraph on mass. If you combine less efficient engines, less efficient staging (which means carrying dead mass for a minute, everything but negligible), and nearly 25% lower liftoff mass, it wouldn't surprise me that much.

Bear in mind, we don't have access to a lot of important numbers too: each vehicle's propellant mass fraction (very important when going to orbit), trajectory optimisations (I can't find a map, but I'm fairly certain launching to LEO from ISRO's launch complex requires a dogleg bend during the ascent).

Comment: @cesarparent another very important element is that the difference at thrust becomes very big.Because after 100s total thrust of GSLV MKII is only 3040 kN since the solid core stage has finished.Falcon 9FT thrust keeps rising,in vacuum it will be 8227 kN.This makes a big difference in payload.Another thing is that 2nd 3rd stage of GSLV are small. 2nd stage has a low Isp 295s and burns for 150s,compared to Falcon 9 348s burning for 397s. 3rd stage is very small and is used to put a little bit more payload but still can't compesate very big loses in 1st and 2nd stage.You can edit your answer.

Comment: @Mark777, But stage 3 specific impulse is much higher (454), And burns for 720seconds. Does that will not have enough impact?

Comment: We should combine all the elements together here,not taking only one,the Isp of 3rd stage.It has really the Isp 454s but has also a very low thrust 75 kN.And this kind of upper stages are helpful if you have put a big payload in a high orbit where you don't have to do much with gravity.In this case stages that fight gravity have a very low performance.At that moment that 3rd stage will be ignited the payload would be very small because it has lost to much performance in 1st stage mostly and 2nd.Combine all disadvantages of cesarparent and what I wrote,will give this performance for GSLV.

Comment: @amyinorbit Shriharikota (13°N) has lower latitude than Merritt Island/Cape Canaveral (28°N)... Doglegging should be less intense for GSLV, unless I misunderstand the concept of dogleg

Comment: @MilindR, yes, you appear to be misunderstanding the concept of a dogleg.  What you are thinking of is (probably) an inclination change manœuvre.  The best example of inclination change was during the launch of IXPE.  A dogleg is when you need to 'go around' something during a launch.  An example would have been the H3 Maiden flight; but conceptually: imagine you are launching towards the west from Kennedy Space Centre.  You can't fly over Florida because if the rocket RUDs, people might die.  You _dogleg_ around Florida to avoid flying over it.

Comment: That's also (one of the reasons) why westward launches in the USA liftoff from Vandenberg.

Comment: Ah thanks, understood. In case of Shriharikota, there's nothing around in the general eastern direction for at least 1500 km.

Answer (score 0):

The additional velocity  Del V is only matter in addition to total impulse.  Velocity at the end GSLV is 2km/sec where as Falcon 2.5 km/sec.  And at the end of Gs2 stage velocity is 3.4km/sec where as Falcon will go 4.km /sec in the same regime n further takes faster. That makes the payload difference.  Also another factor is launch location site.