# Have there been any correlations between rocket size and the delta V it achieves

Tags: launch, delta-v

Have there been any studies that discuss the delta V of the vehicle and compare it to the altitude of operation, or compare it across launchers. If not, what kind of criteria, would one look for across launchers that could help compare them in this aspect.

Comment: Many different rockets place payloads in LEO by producing approximately the same delta-v. What is the gist of your question?

Comment: but their sizes, engines and payload masses are different. I wanted to see if we kept that constant, would the delta-V change. So, I wanted to see if there's a study already done, and if not, how one could go about it.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/why-are-rocket-mass-on-the-launch-pad-and-payload-mass-to-leo-not-strongly-corre/10674

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wonder if answers to that question could be loosely paraphrased as "financial inertia over translational inertia"?

Comment: I wonder if a "Scoville plot" for launch vehicles is possible? I saw the tweet ;-)

Comment: Not to be too snide about it, but this is pretty much what the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation itself is.